# Store State Issues - Next Redux Wrapper vs Redux ToolKit

Tags: next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, next-redux-wrapper

**FYI: Everything is working fine and all the flows are working as expected but logs are confusing.**

I am using Redux ToolKit for managing redux state & using Next Redux Wrapper for Server Side rendering and caching queries.

**CartSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: { data: [] },
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      const itemInCart = state.data.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);
      if (itemInCart) {
        itemInCart.quantity += action.payload.quantity;
      } else {
        state.data.push({ ...action.payload });
      }
    }
  },
});

export const cartReducer = cartSlice.reducer;
export const { addToCart } = cartSlice.actions;
```

**ServiceApi.js**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper'

export const serviceApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'serviceApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '<base-url>' }),
  extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
    if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
      return action.payload[reducerPath]
    } 
  },

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getItemById: builder.query({ query: (id) => `id/${id}` }),
    getItems: builder.query({ query: () => `/` }),
  }),
})

export const { getRunningQueriesThunk } = serviceApi.util
export const { useGetItemByIdQuery, useGetItemsQuery } = serviceApi
export const { getItemById, getItems } = serviceApi.endpoints;
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { serviceApi } from './serviceApi'
import { createWrapper } from "next-redux-wrapper";
import { cartSlice } from "./cartSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [cartSlice.name]: cartSlice.reducer,
    [serviceApi.reducerPath]: serviceApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(serviceApi.middleware),
  })

const makeStore = () => store
export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore, {debug: true});
```

Using getServerSideProps

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) => async (context) => {
    const { id } = context.query;
    store.dispatch(serviceApi.endpoints.getItemById.initiate(parseInt(id)));
    await Promise.all(store.dispatch(serviceApi.util.getRunningQueriesThunk()));
    return {
      props: {},
    };
  }
);
```

And using wrappedStore

```
const { store, props } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(pageProps);
```

On the UI flows everything is working as expected and i am able to add items in the cart and i can see the store state is getting updated by looking the UI.

But the logs from next redux wrapper is confusing:

[image: See this screenshot, i have items added in my cart (i.e. store state) but i see in the below logs its showing cart data as empty [] which is confusing]

Comment: What do you find confusing about these? Also, are you using `getServerSideProps` at all? If yes, please share that code.

Comment: The confusing is that in the logs (screenshot above) cart reducer has data as empty [] although i added items in cart and it was showing up in UI but somehow not updating here. So not sure if there are multiple stores which got created and not synced.

Comment: Yes I am using getServerSideProps. I have added code snippet above

Comment: If you are doing those logs on the server: the server starts empty at every render and never knows about the state on the client - how could it? New state from the server is transported to the client and "synced in" (if you wire that up), but never from client to server.

Comment: Yes these are from server logs and I got it, but is there any way i remove cart: data [] from server logs. Also i see the same empty array even in browser console which is client logs

Comment: No, because that is part of your Redux store - you configure your store with it, no matter if used or not. And yes, on the browser I would assume that it is empty as well - until you fill it?

Comment: Couple of questions: do we need to setup 2 different redux stores one for server side query and one for client side or same redux store should be used. What the recommended approach? And I am filling it but in browser console it showing empty

Comment: Use the same. Don't look at the console in the browser, but at the Redux Devtools. Maybe you are logging at a bad moment in time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. With Redux Dev Tool my confusion is clear and thankyou for resolving my query.